# IE7 float not working correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm creating a blog that you can see [here](http://trident-it.com/blog/) It works wonderfully in everything except ie7.  You'll notice that the right hand column will drop to the bottom of the page in ie7.  I haven't been able to figure out why or what I am overlooking since I have used this technique several times before with no problems.

Comment: looks like your Div with ID = "InteriorContent" takes up too much space on the screen. (946 px) Try to reduce that and then maybe the right column will snug in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from width and less padding to divs, set float: left to the "InteriorContent" div. This div is floating no where and I guess this might be the cause..